# Parse save new user data in android studio

Tags: android

I have a User database and i would like to add a new column (fullname (string)) .

Below is the code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.parse.SignUpCallback;

import comevidentia.wix.evidentia.www.krudyapp.R;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 Button signup;
 String usernametxt;
 String passwordtxt;
 String emailtxt;
 String fullnametxt;
 EditText fullname;
 EditText password;
 EditText username;
 EditText email;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

 final ImageButton btnOpenPopup2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.openpopup2);
 btnOpenPopup2.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

 @Override
 public void onClick(View arg0) {
 LayoutInflater layoutInflater
 = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
 .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_popup2, null);
 final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
 popupView,
 ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
 ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

 Button btnDismiss = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
 btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 popupWindow.dismiss();
 }
 });

 popupWindow.showAsDropDown(btnOpenPopup2, 50, -30);

 }
 });

 final ImageButton btnOpenPopup3 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.openpopup3);
 btnOpenPopup3.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

 @Override
 public void onClick(View arg0) {
 LayoutInflater layoutInflater
 = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
 .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_popup3, null);
 final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
 popupView,
 ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
 ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

 Button btnDismiss = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
 btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 popupWindow.dismiss();
 }});

 popupWindow.showAsDropDown(btnOpenPopup3, 50, -30);

 }});

 // Locate EditTexts in main.xml
 fullname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fullname);
 username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
 password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
 email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);

 signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signup);

 // Sign up Button Click Listener
 signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

 public void onClick(View arg0) {
 // Retrieve the text entered from the EditText
 fullnametxt = fullname.getText().toString();
 usernametxt = username.getText().toString();
 passwordtxt = password.getText().toString();
 emailtxt = email.getText().toString();

 // Force user to fill up the form
 if (fullnametxt.equals("") && usernametxt.equals("") && passwordtxt.equals("") && emailtxt.equals("")) {
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
 "Kérlek töltsd ki az űrlapot!",
 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 } else {
 // Save new user data into Parse.com Data Storage
 ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
 user.setFullname(fullnametxt);
 user.setUsername(usernametxt);
 user.setPassword(passwordtxt);
 user.setEmail(emailtxt);
 user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
 public void done(ParseException e) {
 if (e == null) {
 // Show a simple Toast message upon successful registration
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
 "Sikeres regisztrálás! Lépj be!",
 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 } else {
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
 "Regisztrációs hiba", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
 .show();
 }
 }
 });
 }

 }
 });
 }
```

Here I get error:

// Save new user data into Parse.com Data Storage

ParseUser user = new ParseUser();

user.setFullname(fullnametxt);

//setFullname = i get error:

I would like to add fullname to the database.

How can I do this?

I can add only the username, email, password -->it is basic --> I found it here:https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseUser.html#setUsername%28java.lang.String%29

I am using Android Studio.

[show the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhMoC.png)

Thank you!

Comment: What is the error you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it with a key and value pair. For example:

```
user.put("fullname" , fullnametxt);
```

Refer to this [link](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#objects-saving-objects). Check this [link](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#users-signing-up) for an example on SignUp.

Answer (score 0):

Check this Answer..

```
  ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
        user.setEmail(emai.getText().toString());
        user.setUsername(emai.getText().toString());
        user.setPassword(password.getText().toString());
        user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException er) {
                if (er != null) {
                    Log.e("ERROR",er.getMessage().toString());
                    Toast.makeText(Form.this,"User Already login are exist!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {

                    Log.e("hello","New User Are Add Informatin");
                }
            }
        });
```

this code is add new user in the parse Table.